# GridView is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page (which has a MasterPage) with a GridView and an SqlDataSource. If I set SelectCommand in the markup, the GridView is displayed fine. But if I generate the same SelectCommand dynamically, the GridView is empty. And I know that the query is executed.
What can be the reason for it?
Thanks.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookList %>" DataSourceMode="DataSet" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookList.ProviderName %>" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>  

        <asp:GridView ID="grdUsers" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="true" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            Width="1480px" Height="100%" PageSize="50" DataSourceID="UserSqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="ID">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternatingrowstyle" />
                <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                        
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                        

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindUsers();
    }
}

protected void BindUsers()
{
    string strSelectClause = 
        @"SELECT ID, Name, FirstName, LastName, EMail, 
      FROM User WHERE Name NOT IN ('*All', 'Admin', 'TPS') ";

    string strQuery = strSelectClause + GenerateWhereClause() + " ORDER BY Name;";

    SqlDataSource UserSqlDataSource = GetControl(this, "UserSqlDataSource") as SqlDataSource;
    UserSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = strQuery;
    grdUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I removed DataSourceID from GridView's markup and added 
        grdUsers.DataSource = UserSqlDataSource; in code behind. 
I wonder why it didn't work the way it was before...

Comment: How about marking as correct answer, or editing the question?

Comment: Click on the check next to the answer. (under the answer's score)  You should always mark an answer as accepted (assuming there is one).

Answer (score 1):

User is a reserved keyword, have you tried:

```
SELECT ID, Name, FirstName, LastName, EMail, 
      FROM [User] WHERE Name NOT IN ('*All', 'Admin', 'TPS') ";
```

Comment: No, it is not the problem. As I said, the GridView is populated with this very SelectCommand if it is set in markup. And I tried the query in QueryBrowser successfully. Anyway, I tried to make this change, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

From [the MSDN documentation for the SqlDataSource control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w.aspx):

> **Note**
>   By default, if one of the parameters is null when you execute a Select command, no data will be returned and no exception will be thrown. You can change this behavior by setting the CancelSelectOnNullParameter property to false.

Comment: Thank you Joel. Unfortunately, this didn't help, either :(

Comment: Almost 4 years later and this has helped me. I have a stored procedure and the URL for it may not have all the parameters. Apparently the CancelSelectOnNullParameter property was getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set the SelectCommand too late in the page life cycle? Do you call grdUsers.DataBind() after setting the SelectCommand?

Comment: Yes, it is in the code I provided in my question. I don't know how it could be late, if it is in the Page_Load().