# Gridview is not displayed when using stored procedure in SQLDatasource

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, sqldatasource

I stumbled across this before and I know it is a common problem. One related question is [GridView is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5596451/777982). But it does not solve my problem.

Ideally what I want is update my gridview depending on the value in a textbox when I click the 'Find' button. It does work for me in my other page. But I have some problem here. I have not changed any default parameters. Here is the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="companyname" HeaderText="companyname" 
            SortExpression="companyname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactfirstname" HeaderText="contactfirstname" 
            SortExpression="firstname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactlastname" HeaderText="contactlastname" 
            SortExpression="lastname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phonenumber" HeaderText="phonenumber" 
            SortExpression="phonenumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactid" HeaderText="contactid" 
            SortExpression="contactno" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In my "Find" Button click event. I am using this code

```
protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind(); /* Edit: I don't need this, I realized */
}
```

But it does not load anything. The whole gridview dos not appear. If I use select statement, the gridview does appear with results. I have tested my storedprocedure inside the gridview and it works the way it should. Don't know what exactly could be the problem here? Anyone came across it?

I think I read somewhere if the stored procedure returns 0 results, gridview will not be displayed.

My SQLDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDBconn %>" 
    SelectCommand="usp_GetContactNo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="" FormField="txtCompanyName" 
            Name="companyname" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="txtFirstName" Name="firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="txtLastName" Name="lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="txtPhone" Name="phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="txtContactID" Name="contactNo" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

StoredProcedure is below. Note I might have changed some names above for security reasons but below is the original fields.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetContactIDs] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @companyname varchar(255) = NULL, 
    @firstname varchar(255) = NULL,
    @lastname varchar(255) = NULL,
    @phone varchar(10) = NULL,
    @contactid varchar(15) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @sql varchar(1000);



    set @sql = 'select ID, companyname,contactfirstname,contactlastname,phonenumber, contactid from oet WHERE ID is not null'

    if(@companyname is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND companyname = '''+ @companyname + '''';

    if(@firstname is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND contactfirstname = '''+ @firstname + '''';

    if(@lastname is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND contactlastname = '''+ @lastname + '''';

    if(@phone is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND phonenumber = '''+ @phone + '''';

    if(@contactid is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND contactid = '''+ @contactid + '''';


    exec (@sql)


END
```

Comment: Why are you calling `DataBind()` on the `SqlDataSource`?  Is that the only thing the Find button is doing?

Comment: Yes, it is needed to update the grid view.

Comment: correction: You are right `DataBind()` is not needed.

Comment: can you post your SP please ?

Comment: Stored Procedure posted. This works fine the regular way and inside SQL Datasource test query but not on the page.

Comment: What I found so far is nothing is passed to the SQL SP, weather the field is blank or non-empty. I removed all conditions from SP and it does pull data now. For that work, you have to set "CancelSelectOnNullParameter" to False in SQLDataSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me more than a day to solve it. **The problem was Master pages**. when I removed the master page from the page everything worked fine. What was happening is txtFirstName control was on the page, but it was never found since I was using a master page. As a result it was passing a null value every time. It did not produce any error (which is should), that made debugging very tricky.

There were a bunch of other properties that you need to look at. Important ones are

In SQL DataSource, configur DataSource, Parameter section : select the parameter and click on 'show advance options', ConvertEmptyStringToNull. You may need to change it to false.

SQLDatasourc -> Properites -> CancelSelectOnNullParamter = change it to false

Comment: if you're using FindControl in C# then there shouldn't be a problem with finding the textbox name by id if it exist on the same page, so I don't where you think your problem was

Comment: I am not using any C# code. Everything is ASP. I am looking at $ operator now to fix findcontrol problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced similar trouble, at last I solved it by set the **CancelSelectOnNullParameter** *false* in [SqlDataSource]->[Properties] view or code as: `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="..." runat="server" ... CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">`

this is easily missed if your store procedure allow null parameters as it's set true as default

Comment: This was a life saver. Seriously, who at MSFT thought of making the default for this to be "true"?